# Android 10-System.NotSupportedException:Unable to activate instance of type Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform+DefaultRenderer from native handle

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing xamarin app. When I try to open(open and close and open again) a popup page multiple times app gets crash. it is showing exception below. This is happening in **only Android 10** where as below android 10 it's working fine and I am not using any custom views and custom view renders on that pages.

System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform+DefaultRenderer from native handle 0xbbf7072c (key_handle 0xef667e7). ---> System.MissingMethodException: No constructor found for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform+DefaultRenderer::.ctor(System.IntPtr, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership) ---> Java.Interop.JavaLocationException: Exception of type 'Java.Interop.JavaLocationException' was thrown.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Java.Interop.TypeManager.CreateProxy (System.Type type, System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) [0x00055] in <6f4f555104d84d6daeb9438509841e94>:0
at Java.Interop.TypeManager.CreateInstance (System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer, System.Type targetType) [0x00116] in <6f4f555104d84d6daeb9438509841e94>:0
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Java.Interop.TypeManager.CreateInstance (System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer, System.Type targetType) [0x00182] in <6f4f555104d84d6daeb9438509841e94>:0
at Java.Lang.Object.GetObject (System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer, System.Type type) [0x000c1] in <6f4f555104d84d6daeb9438509841e94>:0
at Java.Lang.Object.*GetObject[T] (System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) [0x00017] in <6f4f555104d84d6daeb9438509841e94>:0
at Java.Lang.Object.GetObject[T] (System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) [0x00000] in <6f4f555104d84d6daeb9438509841e94>:0
at Java.Lang.Object.GetObject[T] (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) [0x00006] in <6f4f555104d84d6daeb9438509841e94>:0
at Android.Views.View.n_SetOnTouchListener_Landroid_view_View_OnTouchListener* (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_l) [0x00000] in <6f4f555104d84d6daeb9438509841e94>:0
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.55(intptr,intptr,intptr)

Comment: How is the popup view that you are trying to call defined for the android project? As the error implies, the fix would be to add a constructor that accepts the following signature, if it is an android specific view: (System.IntPtr, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership)

Comment: I am not using any android specific views in the popup. 

` inpLookupPopup = new InputLookupPopup(GetLookupItems(null, TicketTypes, "ticketType"), false, false, "ticket type");
                    inpLookupPopup.InputLookupItemSelected += InpLookupPopup_InputLookupItemSelected;
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                    {
                        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(inpLookupPopup);
                        //PopupNavigation.PushAsync(inpLookupPopup, false);
                    });
                }`

Comment: Looks like PopupNavigation is a separate nuget package? It is possible that there is an issue within the package itself

Comment: Verify the word using anywhere. I was facing the same issue because something was being disposed of and shouldn´t be done. I didn´t get any direct hint about it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a late answer; but I faced a similar issue in Android crashing when attempting to remove an item from an ObservableCollection that is bound to a FlexLayout.

The solution is wrap the code to run on main thread that is responsible to remove the item from the collection.

`Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { // Remove item from ObservableCollection                 });`